# Java JTable data loading

Tags: java, swing, jtable, event-dispatching

so i have a large cardlayout with one panel as a JTable:

```
tbm = new DefaultTableModel();  
tbm.addColumn("Account Number"); 
tbm.addColumn("PIN"); 
tbm.addColumn("Access Level"); 
tbm.addColumn("Balance");
table = new JTable(tbm);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

under actionPerformed, I am trying to load some data into the table as follows:

```
else if(event.getSource() == listallButton) {
      String query = "SELECT * FROM ATM";
      String delimiter = ",";
      String input = "go";
      int count=0;
      al = new ArrayList<String>();

          try {
              communicationObject = new DataObject();
              communicationObject.setMessage(query);
              Socket socketToServer = new Socket("sunlab32.njit.edu",31414);
              ObjectOutputStream myOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socketToServer.getOutputStream());
              ObjectInputStream myInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socketToServer.getInputStream());
              myOutputStream.writeObject(communicationObject);
              communicationObject = (DataObject)myInputStream.readObject();
              input = communicationObject.getMessage();
              if (input != "stop") {
                  al.add(input);
                  data[count] = input;
                  count++; }

              for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                  row = data[i];
                  temp = row.split(delimiter);
                  tbm.addRow(new String[] {temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]}); } 
              tbm.fireTableDataChanged();
              table.repaint();
```

now my problem is that the table does not get repainted after all the rows are loaded...any suggestions?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).
 2) Is this [tag:homework]?  If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Answer (score 4):

`tbm.addModel` should be firing table changed event, so `tbm.fireTableDataChanged` is not necessary.

You can try doing this though to force it to paint itself after you have added all the rows.

```
table.setModel(tbm);
```

Off topic:

Swing is a single threaded event model, which means the task that you are carrying out will block UI update.

I would suggest you move your data loading to SwingWorker and once you are done with your changes push the data on the UI. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call `tbm.fireTableDataChanged();`. The model itself will notify the table in response to [addRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). And if the table and model are connected correctly the table will refresh itself.

You may find this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/DefaultTableModeladdRowObjectrowData.htm) helpful, it demos use of `DefaultTableModel`.

As this code is not visible, make sure the table and scroll pane are setup correctly. Also, make sure your query actually returns data.